# Why does Xcode not see my Cocoa Touch Framework in my project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, compiler-errors, swift-class

I created an Xcode project and then added a Cocoa Touch Framework target. I then drag and dropped files from another instance of Xcode with a different Cocoa Touch Framework project open.

Why doesn't Xcode see the declared identifiers in my framework?

In other words, when I embed or link the framework in a target in a project, the target cannot see the classes declared in the framework.

The other questions on stack**overflow** did not help.

[image]

I noticed that the Target Membership settings for the swift files in the framework only has the framework checked.

[image]

When I check the other targets, those targets can see what's in the framework. So that solves the problem, but isn't the Target Settings for the swift files in the framework supposed to only have the framework target checked?

Comment: I am sorry, I can't actually follow whats going on here. Can you give us more detail about the problem, as explained here [mcve]?

Comment: @KutayDemireren I added clarification to my question. Here is what I added: "In other words, when I embed or link the framework in a target in a project, the target cannot see the classes declared in the framework."

Comment: @KutayDemireren I noticed something else and added more content to the question -- about the Target Membership settings.